# why `view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b)` is diffrent for the same doc?

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3

I need to get the scope when I create a *.sublime-snippet.The command `view.scope_name(view.sel()[0].b)` is what I stumbled across for the ST2 console that conveniently outputs the scope name of the currently-selected tab.

I tested it in the ST console several times, however, it output the different result.

I just want to know why this happens?(BTW, I use mac)

[image]

And I also curious that what is `view.sel()[0].b` mean? What's mean of the arg `point` of the scope_name method?（the officail API Reference demonstrates scope_name(point) means the syntax scope name assigned to the character at the given point.)

Comment: You saw the command for ST2, but you're working on ST3, maybe that's why.

Comment: well,I don't think so because all of the api can be found in the SUBLIME TEXT 3 DOCUMENTATION refrerence

Comment: `view.sel()[0].b` is the position of the first caret in the document.

Comment: @r-stein well, can u put it in details about `the first caret in the doc`. I have benchmarked that it is the last time position of the cursor when blur the ST window and focus on the ST console.

Comment: @PageYe Sorry I don't understand what might be unclear. Do you know what a caret (aka "text cursor") is?

Comment: @r-stein aha, thank you:~) u r right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to know a scope for any reason (including creating a snippet), by far the simplest solution is to select `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` from the menu (see the menu item to see what the default key binding for your platform is). This will display a popup that shows you the full scope at the current caret location in the document. Using this method you don't need to memorize any API calls.

> I tested it in the ST console several times, however, it output the different result.
>
> I just want to know why this happens?

In a nutshell, every file has a syntax associated with it (based on extension, you specifically telling Sublime what to use, etc), and that syntax scans the entire file applying one or more scopes to each character in the document. The scopes of a character determines how the color scheme you're using colors the text.

As you will see when you perform the above menu command, there can be many scopes that apply to any given cursor location; the farther along the list of scopes a scope is, the more specific the scope becomes. So as you move the cursor through the document, the specificity of that particular character may change, but the first part of the scope remains constant.

As such, unless you want to trigger a snippet only in a really, **really** specific location (e.g. "only in front of a numeric constant that is a function argument in a C# class method) you generally only need the first part of the scope, i.e. `source.js` or `text.html`.

> And I also curious that what is view.sel()[0].b mean?

In Sublime, every tab is represented by a `view` object, which is an object by which all interaction with Sublime for that particular file takes place. For example, editing commands need to be executed on a particular view so that Sublime knows what file you're editing.

Inside of every view there are one or more cursors for editing, and each one of those cursors represents one selected area. This is true even if there is visibly no text selected, in which case the selection has a length of 0.

The call `view.sel()` returns back to you a list of all of the selections that exist inside of that view, with the subscript `[0]` indicating "the first selection". So `view.sel()[0]` means "Give me a reference to the first selection (cursor) in this view".

Every selection is represented by a `Region` object, which is an object that contains two Points, `a` and `b`; `a` is the point at which the selection starts, and `b` is the point at which the selection ends. In the case of a selection that is empty (i.e. just a blinking cursor), `a` and `b` are the same value.

It is possible for `b` to be smaller than `a`, which means that you selected text from right to left instead of left to right. In effect, `b` tells you the point in the selection that the cursor is currently sitting on.

Hence, `view.sel()[0].b` means "Get me a reference to the first selection in this view, and then tell me the point that the cursor in that selection is sitting at".

> What's mean of the arg point of the scope_name method?（the officail API Reference demonstrates scope_name(point) means the syntax scope name assigned to the character at the given point.)

As you may be able to tell from the above, `Point` represents a single location in a document. The first character in a file is at Point 0 and the last character in the file is at point `view.size()` (a method which tells you the number of characters in the current file).

Since the scope of every character in the file is potentially different, the method `scope_name` needs to know what part of the file you want to know the scope for, so it requires you to tell it what position you're asking about.

Comment: when I test the following in ST console, it comes out diffrent value，why?             
`
>>> view.sel()
<sublime.Selection object at 0x1095f0fd0>
>>> view.sel()
<sublime.Selection object at 0x109acdb50>
>>> view.sel()
<sublime.Selection object at 0x1095f0f50>
`

Comment: Every time you make the call it creates a new object, which gets destroyed when you're done with it (garbage collected). The data that the object represents remains the same though, assuming the actual selection does not change.